# Central limit theorem for sequence of r.v.s with "extending" uniform distributions

Tags: probability-theory

Does the Central Limit Theorem hold for independent r.v. $U_n \sim \mathrm{U}([0,n])$? Are there any deterministic $a_n, b_n$ such that
$$
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n U_k - a_n}{b_n} \implies \mathrm{N}(0,1)
$$

I guess the answer is no. Do I have to prove that Lindeberg's condition($\forall \epsilon > 0\frac{1}{b_n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb{E}(X_k - m_k)^2\mathbb{1}_{(|X_k - m_k| > \epsilon b_n)} \to 0$ as n $\to \infty$) can not hold?

Comment: No it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you talking about individual $U_n$ or $\sum U_n$ ?

Comment: @Henry Oh, $\sum U_n$. I have edited the question.

Comment: @math_beginner Please think more carefully about what it is you want to ask. Currently your notation does not make sense. Do you mean $\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n U_i) - a_n}{b_n}$? or something else? Some sanity checks you can do is checking that the mean and variance of your terms must tend to $0$ and $1$ respectively; this should help determine what $a_n$ and $b_n$ _could_ be, and then you can check if the limiting distribution is normal or not (if it exists at all).

Comment: The sum of the first $n$ uniform random variables has mean $n(n+1)/4$ and, assuming independence, a standard deviation of $\sqrt{n(n+1)(2n+1)/72}$